# Как написать регулярное выражение для поиска строк со словом 'acfj'?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++11, std-regex

Как написать паттерн регулярного выражения для поиска строк со словом 'acfj' в текстовом файле ?

До этого слова в строке может быть любое количество пробельных символов или символов табуляций или символов переноса строки (возможно, нулевое). Перед буквой 'a' не может стоять ни цифры, ни буквы, но может стоять какой-то символ, например '[' или '*' или какой-то еще.

Аналогично после этого слова в строке может быть любое количество пробельных символов или символов табуляций или символов переноса строки (возможно, нулевое). После буквы 'j' не может стоять ни цифры, ни буквы, но может стоять какой-то символ, например '[' или '*' или какой-то еще.

Пробую так:

```
std::string someLine;
const std::regex pattern("([\\s])([a]{1}[c]{1}[f]{1}[j]{1})([\\s])");
if ( std::regex_match( someLine, pattern ) ) {
    std::cout << "line: '" << someLine << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Только не забывайте, что в общем случае регэкспы это зло. В больших программах они иногда приводят к неотлаживаемым ошибкам на этапе сопровождения (поскольку большая часть программистов толком в них не разбирается)

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, `[a]{1}` равноценно `a` (символ появляется 1 раз)

Мой вариант выражения:

```
^\s*[^\w]?acfj[^\w]?\s*$
```

По пунктам:
`^` - начало строки
`\s*` - любое количество пробельных символов или символов табуляций или символов переноса строки (возможно, нулевое).
`[^\w]?` - Перед буквой 'a' не может стоять ни цифры, ни буквы, но может стоять какой-то символ, например '[' или '*' или какой-то еще. (`\w` — это буква, цифра или символ подчеркивания.)
`acfj` - собственно, `acfj`.
`[^\w]?` - После буквы 'j' не может стоять ни цифры, ни буквы, но может стоять какой-то символ, например '[' или '*' или какой-то еще.
`\s*` - после этого слова в строке может быть любое количество пробельных символов или символов табуляций или символов переноса строки (возможно, нулевое).
`$` - конец строки.

Не забудьте экранировать все `\` когда будете вставлять код.

Отмечу, что если посреди строки встречается символ переноса строки, то у нас получается уже две строки. Мне это условие не очень понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, можно и короче, но это хотя бы работает (и работает быстро):

```
/^(?:[^\n]*[^a-z0-9а-яё\n])?acfj(?:[^a-z0-9а-яё\n][^\n]*)?$/gmi
```

https://regex101.com/r/a5aru1/1